# TeamCity build agent connected and disconnected at the same time

Tags: teamcity, agent

guys.

I'm having some trouble with TeamCity build agents.

I have an agent i'm using for calabash automation. When i'm running the build i'm getting :

Agent didn't come for the command in a 30 seconds.

I can see my agent in "Connected agents" tab, and "Disconnected" tab, and builds are not running. I tried to reboot the machine several times, and restarting the agent daemon on that machine, nothing happens, even when I shut down the machine it's still in "connected" and "disconnected" tabs.

Comment: Is "Agent didn't come for the command in a 30 seconds." a real message by TeamCity? I've never seen it, and it's very strange English too.

Comment: That's what is displayed in build log.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42406) in TeamCity 9.1.x which is fixed in 9.1.4 which may cause such problem. You could use workaround from issue comments.

Comment: Note that TeamCity 9.1.4 not released yet (14-Oct-2015).